# Invalid object name

Tags: c#

The first one is function with query to access information about driver from table tblDDDDriver by using VehicleNumber which is one of the field or column name in tblDDDDriver.
The second one is what i coded to access that function.
Now when i click the button i shows the error  Invalid object name 'tblDDDDriver'

```
public DataTable GetDriverByVehicalNumber(string VehicleNumber)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB; Integrated Security=True; Initial Catalog=tprojectDB;");
        string sql = "select *from tblDDDDriver where VehicleNumber=@VehicleNumber";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VehicleNumber", VehicleNumber);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);

        return dt;
    }



 private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = dc.GetDriverByVehicalNumber(txtvehicleno.Text);
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            txtlicenseno.Text = dt.Rows[0]["LicenseNumber"].ToString();
            txtlicensecategory.Text = dt.Rows[0]["LicenseCategory"].ToString();
            txtissuedate.Text = dt.Rows[0]["IssueDate"].ToString();
            txtrenewdate.Text = dt.Rows[0]["RenewDate"].ToString();
            txtfullname.Text = dt.Rows[0]["FullName"].ToString();
            txtdob.Text = dt.Rows[0]["DOB"].ToString();
            txtaddress.Text = dt.Rows[0]["Address"].ToString();
            string gender = dt.Rows[0]["Gender"].ToString();
            if (gender == "Male")
            {
                txtgender.Text = " MALE";
            }
            else
            {
                txtgender.Text = "FEMALE";
            }
            txtvehicleno.Text = dt.Rows[0]["VehicleNumber"].ToString();
            txthealthstaus.Text = dt.Rows[0]["HealthStatus"].ToString();
            txtdrivertype.Text = dt.Rows[0]["DriverType"].ToString();

            Image img;
            byte[] bytimg = (byte[])dt.Rows[0]["Image"];

            //convert byte of imagedate to Image format
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytimg, 0, bytimg.Length))
            {
                ms.Write(bytimg, 0, bytimg.Length);

                img = Image.FromStream(ms, true);

                pictureBox1.Image = img;
            }

        }
        DataTable dd = dc.GetMaxDeathNo(Convert.ToDecimal(txtlicensenumber.Text));
        if (dd.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            txtdeathaccidentno.Text = dd.Rows[0]["DeathNumber"].ToString();
        }

        DataTable dM = dc.GetMaxMajorNo(Convert.ToDecimal(txtlicensenumber.Text));
        if (dM.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            txtmajoraccidentno.Text = dM.Rows[0]["MajorNumber"].ToString();
        }

        DataTable dm = dc.GetMaxMinorNo(Convert.ToDecimal(txtlicensenumber.Text));
        if (dm.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            txtminoraccidentno.Text = dm.Rows[0]["MinorNumber"].ToString();
        }

        DataTable dtrb = dc.GetTrafficRuleBroken(Convert.ToDecimal(txtlicensenumber.Text));
        {
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dtrb;
        }

    }
```

Comment: you haven't opened the connection before using it. Secondly, check whether connection string is pointing to the right database.

Comment: Hope you are pointing to correct db in connection string. Does the query work in SSMS?

Comment: @Harsh - There is no need to open and close sql connection explicitly when using `SqlDataAdapter` because it does that for you internally.

Comment: ah, my bad! didn't see that @dotnetkid

Comment: `select *from tblDDDDriver where VehicleNumber=@VehicleNumber` Just wondering is it your select statement here wrote wrong .. The `*from` this will return you error due to statement is incorrect..